# comparing dates with sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to compare the date of my Last B Service + Service interval months to todays date in Sharepoint. But it is giving me an error.

```
=IF(DATE(YEAR([Last B Service]),
MONTH([Last B Service])+[B Service Monthly Interval], 
DAY([Last B Service])),"D")) >= NOW(), 0, 1)
```

I add B Service Monthly Interval to the Months section in the Date variable, then try and compare it to NOW() (todays date) to make this example easier, i have changed the result to 0 and 1 (i ahve also tested this and it returns an error)

Can you see whats wrong with that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the `"D"` is doing in your formula as all the parentheses around that area make the formula invalid (you actually tried to close the `IF` after `"D"`.

I don't know if it makes sense, but the following formula **would** work:

```
=IF(DATE(YEAR([Last B Service]);MONTH([Last B Service])+[B Service Monthly Interval];DAY([Last B Service])) >= NOW();0;1)
```

Here comes the trick: SharePoint calculated columns formula are largely compatible to Excel! What I actually did to try this out:

1. Open a new sheet
2. Write "4/14/13" into `A1` (the last service)
3. Write "3" into `B2` (the service interval)
4. Create the formula in `C3`: `=IF(DATE(YEAR(A1);MONTH(A1)+B1;DAY(A1)) >= NOW();0;1)`
5. Profit

Comment: arhhh! you are right.. its because I had DATEDIFF originally for something else.